# Current distribution in a circuit that includes current and voltage sources

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, current, kirchhoffs-laws

[image]

The question asks us to find \$ V_{c1} \$ and \$ V_{c2} \$ .
The equivalent circuit is below. My lecturer drew the currents as in the picture.

[image]

And here is my lecturer's solution for calculating the currents:
[image]

The sum of currents is 3 A. So, it seems like the voltage source does not produce any current. Is that true?

Comment: If the voltage at node A is larger than 9V battery voltage then yes, the voltage source does not produce any current. In this case, the voltage source is "charged" by a current source.

Comment: @G36 So the voltage source spends energy and this circuit is valid.

Comment: In this circuit, the battery is charge, thus "draws energy" (absorbe power).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, it seems like the voltage source does not produce any current. Is that true?

Assuming the calculations are correct: it doesn’t have to produce current.

When you disconnect the voltage source, the current source develops exactly 9V on the terminals where the voltage source was connected. As you reconnect the voltage source, there’s no potential difference and thus no further current flows from it.

This “disconnection” operation is formalized as the superposition method. You can analyze a linear circuit with only one independent source connected at a time, repeat the analysis for each source, and then just linearly add up the partial solutions for voltages and currents at each node/component. This doesn’t generally work if the circuit is nonlinear, ie. if it has dependent sources like transistors or op-amps. In specific cases it may work, but that’s the exception not the rule.

The problem circuit was designed specifically to illustrate such a situation where the voltage source produces no current. Such a perfect match is rare in practical circuits, unless they were designed to make it happen.

Answer (score 2):

In ideal circuit analysis, an ideal voltage source does not **produce** a current...it **constrains** the voltage between its two terminals. Current may flow either direction through an ideal voltage source and we can still have a valid circuit.

If a positive current flows **into** the positive terminal of an ideal voltage source with a positive voltage value, then the source is absorbing power.

Comment: Do voltage sources absorbe power?

Comment: Yes generators can become motors and Voltage sources (ideal) may source or sink. But LDO's are unipolar are not ideal and only source as low dropout regulators

Comment: Consider a battery.. Charge/discharge